# How to change the output date format of input type="date" in angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

Actually I am working with angular 4 application. I am having a scenario like, I have to send the Date for as **dd/mm/yyyy** to the server.

I am using property as input type ="date". But this property returns the value like **yyyy/mm/dd**. so how do I change the output format of the Date.

**Students.html**

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="Students.dob" name="Students.dob">
```

After selecting the date, when I am check with console.log().

**Students.components.ts**

```
checkDate() { console.log(Students.dob); }
```

Finally the output was **yyyy/mm/dd.**.

Is there any way to overcome this issue? kindly let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could change the date into **`dd/mm/yyyy`** format using **`DatePipe`** inside the `checkDate()` function. like below. And send that date into the server side.

first import the **`DatePipe`** into your component

```js
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

then use it like below

```js
  checkDate() {
    const dateSendingToServer = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(this.Students.dob, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
    console.log(dateSendingToServer);
  }
```

working example you could be found here on  <kbd>[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xuvrtq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)</kbd>.

Hope this will help to you!

Answer (score 2):

You could try this -

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

checkDate() {
    let formatedDate = new DatePipe().transform(this.Students.dob, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
    console.log(formatedDate); 
  }
```

Comment: is there any solution to work this method <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="Students.dob|date:'dd/MM/yyyy'" name="Students.dob">

Answer (score 0):

You can use DatePipe method.

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="Students.dob|date:'dd/MM/yyyy'" name="Students.dob">
```

You can read more from here.
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: When I use the Pipe expression in the ngModel shows error like "Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 16 in [students.doj | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'=$event] in"

Comment: @VigneshMohanraj If you one-way bind the model like `[ngModel]="Students.dob|date` you can use this.

Comment: But the question specifies 2-way data binding

Comment: you shuold use `[ngModel] = "Students.dob|date" ` and `(onModelChange)="Students.dob=$event" `

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)**. Also, you need to install and import it.

```
npm install moment --save
```

```js
import * as moment from 'moment'; //in your component
```

then use

```js
checkdate(){
   const date = moment(Students.dob).format(DD-MM-YYYY);
   console.log(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the html templates and solved it like this:

1. Go to your app.module.ts search for the providers and insert `DatePipe`
2. go into the html template where you want to change the date format and change it like that `{{Students.dob | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}`
3. Save the two edited files and check how you date is displayed :)