# How to display calendar date mm-dd-yyyy format in input search tag in angular?

Tags: angular

I am using  <input class="input-group1 search" id="to" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" [(ngModel)]="toDate" value="" name="dp3"  type="date">
in my code, because of this calendar is getting displayed in yyyy-mm-dd format , but i want to display it in dd-mm-yyyy format?
How can i do it using input search tag for calendar?

Comment: You can use ```ng2-date-picker``` as you can not programmatically change the format of ```input``` tag. Here is the official doc:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-date-picker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the output date format of input type="date" in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50445363/how-to-change-the-output-date-format-of-input-type-date-in-angular-4)

Comment: hi @IvanaTrošić , yes! I referred this link but it didnt help me. I want to show calendar also on the UI

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
{{ toDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
{{ toDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}
```

If you want time also then use

```
{{ toDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss' }}
```